# jQuery - Adding multiple values together is checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, sum, addition

I have a quote form on a page (made using Gravity Forms WP plugin, but that doesn't matter). The form has multiple checkboxes on it - call these options. Each option has a different value 'assigned' to it. What I want to do, is add these values together if that particular checkbox is ticked, and subtract it's value if it's not. I hope that makes sense...?

Here is what I have so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery('#choice_2_10_4, #choice_2_10_5').change( function() {
        var option1 = Number( jQuery('#choice_2_10_4:checked').val() || 0 ); // Add 250 if checked
        var option2 = Number( jQuery('#choice_2_10_5:checked').val() || 0 ); // Add 200 if checked
        jQuery('#quote-price').val( option1 + option2 );
    });
});
```

`#quote-price` is the field I'd like to show the total of the calculation in.

Can i give `#choice_2_10_4` and `#choice_2_10_5` a value by changing them to:

```
jQuery('#choice_2_10_4:checked').val(250)
jQuery('#choice_2_10_5:checked').val(250)
```

Or something along those lines?

Thanks

Comment: Doing `jQuery('#choice_2_10_4:checked').val(250)` will change the `value` attribute of the checkbox. But what's your question overall? Because your first part looks fine, and your second part could easily be tested without asking.

Comment: Checking the boxes changes the #quote-price value to NaN...?

Comment: Oh...Haha sorry. Basically, it's an instant quote form, so checking certain things on the form changes the total price to whatever all the checkboxes add up to. I would show you but it's built localhost so I can't.

Comment: Can you make a snippet of your problem? Or even a jsfiddle. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @A. Lau - Here you go, this is basically what I have... https://jsfiddle.net/t1ubz3qy/3/

Comment: so why can't you just put the value into the checkbox in the first place? e.g. `<input type="checkbox" value="250" />` ? https://jsfiddle.net/t1ubz3qy/5/

Comment: I completely forgot you could adjust the values in Gravity Forms - that's done the trick! Thanks, been pulling my hair out for ages doing this!

Comment: most of the problems can be resolved via console.log. If you didn't Number it you could just log out the problem. I'll add it as an answer so you don't forget

Comment: I would seriously do some maintenance on the usage of classes/id's on your elements (if possible). Makes life so much easier. For example, Instead of assigning unique class names for your ```<li>```, why don't you assign a class name of ```option``` or something like that. That way, you only have to code 1 event listener to do your logic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the value but after that you have to trigger the change event like so:

```
jQuery('#choice_2_10_4:checked').val(250).trigger('change');
jQuery('#choice_2_10_5:checked').val(250).trigger('change');
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.choice').on('change', function() {
        var total = 0;
        $('.choice').each(function() {
            total += this.checked ? +this.value : -this.value;
        });
        $('#quote-price').val( total );
    })
    .change();
    $('.add').on('click', function() {
        var target = $(this).data('target'),
            theval = $(target).is(':checked') ? +$(this).data('value') : +$(target).val();
        $(target).val( theval ).trigger('change');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="choice_2_10_4" class="choice" value="200"> 200 
<button type="button" data-target="#choice_2_10_4" data-value="250" class="add">Add 250</button><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="choice_2_10_5" class="choice" value="400"> 400 
<button type="button" data-target="#choice_2_10_5" data-value="350" class="add">Add 350</button><br>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="quote-price"/>
```

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything...?

Comment: Do you have the relevant HTML so I can craft a demo?

Comment: It's usually better to include your minimal HTML as part of the question. See if the demo above is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning a value to the checkboxes via `#choice_2_10_4:checked').val(250)` you can just put the value into the checkbox in the first place e.g. `<input type="checkbox" value="250" />`

Then just call it via `#choice_2_10_4:checked').val()`

When you call `#choice_2_10_4:checked').val(250)` it returns an array of elements.

`console.log()` it to see it for yourself